# How to create two independent columns using the twitter bootstrap grid framework

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I want to create a (more or less Pinterest like) grid layout like in the below below. The two columns have different rows, but do appear side to side. How can I do this using the twitter bootstrap grid framework?

[image]

If I'm not mistaken the normal row/col behaviour would give me the layout below. 
[image]

Comment: explain why regular .row + .col-??-?? dont solve your problem.If it's tiles that you want use masonry or isotope.

Comment: I changed the question to incorporate the reason the normal row/col won't work

Comment: [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) seems like a perfect fit here. Give it a shot. Or maybe you`also want to try [Packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to achieve the layout by using two columns which themselves have rows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="col-xs-12">1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">2</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">3</div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="col-xs-12">5</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6">6</div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">7</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">8</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zz4ug/

Comment: So I should create two columns myself and assign rows to each of them.  I guess the trick is to get these two columns to live next to each other and still have them behave responsively. What's the best approach here, just use flows?

Comment: @koenpeters: what exactly do you mean with responsible? They already are responsible, since I am using the bootstrap grid

Comment: I mean responsive as in responsive design.

Comment: @koenpeters: uh, responsible was a typo on my part. I still don' understand. The grid used by bootstrap is already responsive (just add the `col-*-*` classes for other display sizes and you're good to go)

Comment: I'm sorry. I just now realised that you were using nested rows. Your answer is corect.

Answer (score 0):

Create the illusion of incongruous rows via background color or image:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 red">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 orange">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 red">&nbsp;</div> <--This will appear to be on row 1
        <div class="col-xs-3 blue">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 green">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check out this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cEVQE/)**

Comment: That won't work in my case since the col 1 is effectively split in two rows which will break the content that is in it.

Comment: Is it a matter of the content distorting the row heights or that you are restricted to inserting content on individual rows?